# Formula Calculation embedded in SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables T1 and T2 linked by ID. ID 99, 100 & 101 has a formula in T2 table. I need create a SP/UDF, when I input 5000 to Premium column, FieldValue of 99,100 & 101 should be re-calculated and updated based on the formula in T1, that is Tax=4400, Amount=10400 and Percentage=104. There might be dependency of formula with each other, but it should be calculated on FormulaOrder.

T1

[image]

T2

[image]

```
    create table #T1
(
  ID int, FieldName varchar(50),fieldvalue varchar(50),fieldtypeid int,fieldorder int
);

insert into #T1(ID,FieldName,fieldvalue,fieldtypeid,fieldorder)
values (97,'Coverage','This is Coverage',486,1),
(98,'Premium','6000',485,2),
(99,'Tax','10',488,3),
(100,'Amount','10',488,4),
(101,'Percentage',null,488,5);


create table #T2
(
  ID int, Formula varchar(50),FormulaOrder int
);

insert into #T2(ID,Formula,FormulaOrder)
values (99,'Premium * 0.8',1),
(100,'Premium + Tax',2),
(101,'Amount * 0.01',3);
```

Please do help.

Thanks in advance

Naveen J V

Comment: This is not something that you can do with a query.  You will need to write a stored procedure.

Comment: There are your actual tables? So `T1.FieldValue` is `varchar` and stores numeric data?? What kind of architecture is this?

Comment: FieldValue column is of varchar type. when FieldTypeID is 486, it would contain character data, if 485 then numeric data. 488 is for Formula

Comment: And if you change `ID 98 Premium` from `6000` to f.e. `5000` how we connect this to `T2` where another `IDs` are stored?

Comment: ID 98 is Premium. If I update FieldValue for this, then ID 99 which is Tax has to be recalculated based on formula present in T2. Hope you are clear?

Comment: How many `Premium` with different `IDs` will you have?

Comment: FieldName is always distinct. In this case only one with ID=98

Comment: Good news! In that case you need to create SP. In that SP you should pass `Premium`value. At first update the `fieldvalue` with `id = 98`, than calculate another fields.If you need to get formula from `T2` and it could be changed in future - you should use dynamic SQL to build and execute query to update `99, 100, 101` fields.

Comment: You can try using trigger on Update / INSERT